# Kendo UI loop through collection in Json within template for ListView

Tags: json, listview, templates, razor, kendo-ui

I am trying to figure out within a Kendo UI template for a list view how to loop through a collection within each object to render the information on the page. Here is an example of the json I am playing with:

```
{"Data":[{"Title":"Malicious Acts","KeyPairs":{"Key1":"12","Key2":"24"}},            {"Title":"Enrollments","KeyPairs":{"Key1":"12","Key2":"24"}},{"Title":"Customer Feedback","KeyPairs":{"Key1":"12","Key2":"24"}},{"Title":"Questionable Accounts","KeyPairs":{"Key1":"12","Key2":"24"}}],"Total":4,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

I want to render the KeyPairs items in the template and just an having some trouble understanding how to.

Here is the source:

```
<div id="subscriberFunctions">

    <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
        <div class="subscriberFunction">
            <h3>${Title}</h3>
           <!-- Display KeyPairs -->
        </div>
    </script>

    @(Html.Kendo().ListView<SubscriberMenuFunction>()
        .Name("listView")
        .TagName("div")
        .ClientTemplateId("template")
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("SubscriberMenu", "ListView"));
        })
        .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(ListViewSelectionMode.Single))

    )
</div>
```

I'm sure I'm just overthinking this, and it is something simplistic, but not sure how to implement the foreach loop in the template for Kendo UI to recognize it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do this with a counter in the for-loop. This should fix your issue:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="subscriberFunction">
        <h3>${Title}</h3>
        <!-- Display KeyPairs -->
        <ul>
            #for (var i=0,len=KeyPairs.length; i<len; i++){#
                <li>${ KeyPairs[i] }</li>
            # } #
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: This is a better approach and works great and doesn't bring along the extra code snippet in the output.

Comment: I think you have a typo after "var i=0,"  comma should be a semicolan right?

Comment: ^ I think you have a typo after 'should be a', 'semicolan' should be 'semicolon' right? :P

Comment: I don't know why this has so many upvotes. It was intended to declare 2 variables in the setup, but doesn't work, and is not very readable

Comment: It was intended to declare 2 variables in the setup, hence the comma is correct, but the chat here shows it's not very readable

Answer (score 8):

You can have arbitrary JavaScript code inside a template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="subscriberFunction">
        <h3>${Title}</h3>
       <!-- Display KeyPairs -->
         <ul>
         # for (var key in KeyPairs) { #
              <li>${ KeyPairs[key] }</li>
         # } #
         </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: That got my values but brought along what looks like javascript code:    • 52b1e4cc-5fef-4f5c-a0b5-f054b2cf6655
• function (){return b}
• function (a){var b=this,c,d,e=function(){return b},f;o.fn.init.call(this);for(d in a)c=a[d],d.charAt(0)!="_"&&(f=M.call(c),c=b.wrap(c,d,e)),b[d]=c;b.uid=n.guid()}
• function (a){return this.hasOwnProperty(a)&&a!=="_events"&&typeof this[a]!==r&&a!=="uid"}
• function (){var a={},b,c;for(c in this)if(this.shouldSerialize(c)){b=this[c];if(b instanceof R||b instanceof Q)b=b.toJSON();a[c]=b}return a}
...

Comment: Is KeyPairs a bad name for this example?

Comment: @mservais did you figure out how to get rid of the javascript?  I am facing the same dilemma.

Comment: For those who have problem like @mservais: try loop in KeyPairs.toJSON().

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to loop through the collection once you know the syntax. This is basically Stans answer with clearer syntax.
If you're using a List you can access properties just by adding them, e.g., `<li>#=KeyPairs[i].FooBar#</li>`

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="subscriberFunction">
    <h3>#=Title#</h3>
    <ul>
        # for (var i = 0; i < KeyPairs.length; i++) { #
            <li>#=KeyPairs[i]#</li>
        # } #
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another elegant way of looping though collection within client template

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="subscriberFunction">
        <h3>${Title}</h3>
          # var t=KeyPairs.join('<br>'); # 
          #=t #
    </div>
</script>
```